# What software extends quicktime to support codecs as an alternative to Perian?

Tags: quicktime

Now that Perian is closing its doors (and thus ending support), I'd like to know if there are any alternatives to Perian - specifically alternatives that add Quicktime support for more filetypes (and thus all the benefits with Apples Video editing/burning applications)

Of the alternatives that Perian themselves have suggested, none have Perians integration with Quicktime:

Niceplayer - standalone application that relies on Perian(!)

VLC - standalone application that doesn't integrate with Quicktime

MPlayer - standalone CLI program that doesn't integrate with Quicktime

So, are there any other QuickTime-integrated codec applications out there? Bonus points if like Perian it's one application that bundles many codecs.

Answer (score 3):

If even Perian themselves do not suggest anything that has QuickTime integration — they should know — I assume you are out of luck. I miss Perian, too, but have made the switch to Zongyao Qu’s [MPlayerX](http://mplayerx.org/), which is current, useful and pretty (***not*** the [Sourceforge](http://mplayerosx.sourceforge.net/) flavor!) …